# jquery function with parameters

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have several checkboxes that when checked show a hidden div.  Is there a way to write a jquery function that will show or hide based on whether the checkbox is checked the hidded div?

using just javascript

```
<input type="checkbox" name="box1" id="box1" onclick="function toggle('div1')">
<div id='div1'>
.....
</div>

<input type="checkbox" name="box2" id="box2" onclick="function toggle('div2')">
<div id='div2'>
.....
</div>


<script>
function toggle(id) {
if (this.checked) show(id);
else hide(id);
}
```

where `show()` and `hide()` are functions define to change the display attribue of the id.

Is there some way to do this in jquery where I bind the toggle to the checkbox adn have it toggle an id that is passed somehow?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can try creating a small jQuery plugin:

```
$.fn.toggleCheckboxContainer = function(selector) {
   var toggleObject = $(selector);
   return $(this).each(function() {
      $(this).change(function() {
        $(this).is(':checked') ? toggleObject.show() : toggleObject.hide();
      });
   });
};

$(function() {
    $('#box1').toggleCheckboxContainer('#div1');
    $('#box2').toggleCheckboxContainer('#div2');
});
```

#### jsFiddle example

Comment: +1, I like it! Much nice way that what I was going to write :)

Comment: +1. But I would not prepend '#' and instead pass in a whole selector. That would make it more flexible.

Comment: would this work when the checkbox is checked or unchecked?  Like an event handler?

Comment: great!  thank you!  I love the jsFiddle example thats what really did it for me.